# What database are people using on Rails production machines?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to get started in the Rails word here after the 3.0 upgrade, and it seems mysql support has been stripped out in favor of sqlite.  After spending hours trying to install the mysql2 gem and failing I'm going to try and develop in sqlite, but are people really using that for production?

I'm just about ready to give up and do this project in PHP, but I really want to give rails a shot.  Any help or advice is appreciated.

Comment: what os are you using? if not linux, then you should really give it a try, rails just works out of the box on linux. if you cant, then.. mysql2 can be installed on windows too but its a little complicated.

Comment: please create a question about your mysql2 problems. Remember to mention the versions of everything you're using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL is still *very* common.  The mysql2 gem is in vogue and should not be terribly difficult to install.  Perhaps open a new question with your installation problems.

If you are interested in alternatives to MySQL, ask on [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com).

Except in certain narrow circumstances, don't plan on using SQLite in production.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630/sqlite-vs-mysql for more discussion.

Answer (score 1):

In production people use different ones based on the requirements and hosting servers.

I use [heroku.com](http://www.heroku.com) to host my proudction applications and heroku uses postgres by default.

But I guess more developers still use MySql in production because of its ease of use and non strict sql grammer implementation.

I have even seen really big applications that are run using oracle.

There are few developers who use sqlite in production also esp if they have very low traffic.

Go with sqllite for development and once you are dene with development and if you follow the rails convention like db:seed and migrations it will be pretty easy to move to any database as you want when the application is ready for production.

Comment: Most of the time I have development happening in sqlite eventhough production is in MySQL (or something else).  Its much easier to move single files around in dev than dealing with "real" DB overhead.  It also reinforces the need to keep code DB independent.

Answer (score 0):

No. Sqlite3 is good for development and for standalone apps.

For web development most popular databases are: [MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/), [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/). Also there is some nosql databases such as [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) and [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/)